# Converter .Jar para .Dex

Tags: android, jar, apk

Fala pessoal! Decompilei um apk e ele gerou um arquivo classe.dex. consegui transformar esse arquivo em .jar e agora quero voltar pra .dex. Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Github existe o seguinte projeto: https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar

Você pode baixar a versão compilada em https://sourceforge.net/projects/dex2jar/files/

Dentro da pasta deve conter o `d2j-jar2dex.bat` que faz exatamente o que você precisa.

Os scripts que veem no download:

- d2j-baksmali
- d2j-dex-recompute-checksum
- d2j-dex2jar
- d2j-dex2smali
- d2j-jar2dex
- d2j-jar2jasmin
- d2j-jasmin2jar
- d2j-smali
- d2j-std-apk
- d2j_invoke

Comment: Acho que ele quer reverter de jar para dex de novo. Esse projeto faz isso também?

Comment: @Articuno sim, o nome do comando fala `jar2dex`, existe scripts para converter para ambos e também para APK. PS: Não testei, não posso afirmar a qualidade e/ou *"precisão"*.

Comment: Valeu Jão.. vou tentar aqui e posto o resultado!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, não tem essa bat na basta do git, porém tenho uma outra aqui que tem. Fiz o processo inverso ao que fiz pra converter pra .jar e mesmo assim não funcionou. Me confirma qual a linha que devo digitar no cmd para a conversão. Grato!

Comment: @VsousaValdemir não falei pra baixar do git, olha a resposta novamente, o link das verões prontas para uso estão no sourceforge, é o segundo link.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, então é essa pasta mesmo que eu tenho aqui.. Realmente tem o jar2dex lá, mesmo assim não está convertendo. Estou achando que pode ser alguma coisa referente ao comando no cmd. O que estou colocando é d2j-jar2dex classes.jar

Comment: @VsousaValdemir aparece algum erro?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento aparece o seguinte:C:\ENGENHARIA REVERSA\dex2jar>d2j-jar2dex o C\ENGENHARIA REVERSA\dex2jar\classes.jar classes.dex
d2j-jar2dex -- Convert jar to dex by invoking dx.
usage: d2j-jar2dex [options] <dir>
options:
 -f,--force                   force overwrite
 -h,--help                    Print this help message
 -o,--output <out-dex-file>   output .dex file, default is $current_dir/[jar-nam
                              e]-jar2dex.dex
version: 2.0

C:\ENGENHARIA REVERSA\dex2jar>

Comment: @VsousaValdemir tente o comando assim `cd C:\ENGENHARIA REVERSA\dex2jar` e depois `d2j-jar2dex C:\ENGENHARIA REVERSA\pasta_aonde_esta_o_jar\meujar.jar`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento deu o mesmo erro.. Não sei mais o que pode ser.

Comment: @VsousaValdemir tenta com aspas: `d2j-jar2dex "C:\ENGENHARIA REVERSA\pasta_aonde_esta_o_jar\meujar.jar"`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento consegui!! achei o vídeo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LvHWe0UOkmU    mesmo assim muito obrigado pela ajuda e atenção.